# moving a view multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, uiviewanimation

I got an array "coordList" with arrays holding x-y-coordinates.
I want to move a view along these coordinates.

If you have a better way to do this please tell me how to do it.

The way I do it has a big problem. It jumps directley to the last animation and I know why but not how to fix it.

My code:

```
count = 1;
for(NSArray *array in coordList) {  
    [UIView animteWithDuration:1 animations:^(void){
        CGRect r = [[self.subviews lastObject] frame];  
        r.origin.x = 103*[coordList[count][0]integerValue];  
        r.origin.y = 103*[coordList[count][1]integerValue];  
        [[self.subviews lastObject] setFrame:r];  
        count++;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

Sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: Are you using auto layout? The recommended technique differs based upon autolayout or not. In generally, you'd usually `UIView` class method `animateWithDuration` instead of the old `beginAnimations` and `commitAnimations`, but if using auto layout you change constraints and animated `layoutIfNeeded`, and if not using auto layout, you change `frame` values like you have here (though using block-based animation).

Comment: Ok. I changed it, but still the same problem.

Comment: While my observation about auto layout still stands, I realize I may have mislead you regarding the block-based animation. This is actually one of those animations where old-school `CAKeyFrameAnimation` is probably the way to go. Generally you should use block-based animation, but in this particular case, you're doing something that block-based animation isn't well suited for. My apologies for leading you down the wrong road there. See my answer from demonstration of `CAKeyFrameAnimation`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that you are committing multiple animations regarding the same view, so each time you commit a new animation for that view it overrides the other existing animations.

You need to set up your animations to trigger one after the other.  So a simple for loop won't work that well.

I'd recommend a recursive routine like this:

```
//set a property to keep current count
@property (nonatomic, asssign) NSInteger currentFrame;

//initialize it to 0 on init
currentFrame = 0;

//call this once when ready to animate
[self animationWithCurrentFrame];


//it will call this routine once for each array.
- (void)animationWithCurrentFrame {
    __block NSArray *array = [coordList objectAtIndex:currentFrame];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect r = [[self.subviews lastObject] frame];
                         r.origin.x = 103*[array[0]integerValue];
                         r.origin.y = 103*[array[1]integerValue];
                         [[self.subviews lastObject] setFrame:r];  
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         currentFrame++;
                         if (currentFrame < [coordList count]) {
                             [self animationWithCurrentFrame];
                         }

                     }];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an ideal application of a [`CAKeyFrameAnimation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html). And you do not do a bunch of animations, but rather you define a path, and then perform a single animation, specifying that path as the "position":

```
UIView *viewToAnimate = [self.subviews lastObject];

// create UIBezierPath for your `coordList` array

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(103*[coordList[0][0]integerValue], 103*[coordList[0][1]integerValue])];
for (NSInteger i = 1; i < [coordList count]; i++)
{
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(103*[coordList[i][0]integerValue], 103*[coordList[i][1]integerValue])];
}

// now create animation

CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation.path = [path CGPath];
animation.duration = 2.0;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
[viewToAnimate.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
```

For this to work, you have to add the QuartzCore framework to your project and import the appropriate header at the top of your .m file:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

For more information, see  [Keyframe Animation to Change Layer Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH3-SW8) in the *Core Animation Programming Guide.*

If you're using auto layout, don't forget to reset your constraints for this view when you're done.